# How to eliminate if-else with same condition but different actions inside another if-else?

Tags: java, if-statement

Suppose I have the code like following:

```
int age=(from user input);
int weight=(from user input);

if(age>60){
    if(weight>100){
        function1();
    }else if(weight<40){
        function2();
    }else{
        function3();
    }
}else if(age<20){
    if(weight>100){
        function4();
    }else if(weight<40){
        function5();
    }else{
        function6();
    }
}else{
    if(weight>100){
        function7();
    }else if(weight<40){
        function8();
    }else{
        function9();
    }
}
```

the problem is that the code pattern:

```
if(weight>100){
    //do something different
}else if(weight<40){
    //do something different
}else{
    //do something different
}
```

repeats as there are different ranges of age. And I can't enclose the inner if-else into a single function, because the things to do is different even through the condition is the same. Is there any way to modify this code so that the code pattern:

```
if(age>60){
    //do something different
}else if(age<20){
    //do something different
}else{
    //do something different
}
```

and

```
if(weight>100){
    //do something different
}else if(weight<40){
    //do something different
}else{
    //do something different
}
```

would appear once only?

Comment: have you try switch statement. that makes your code little bit clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing what all your function1-9 do (which would probably be too much code for Stack Overflow anyway), it's hard to give a definitive answer.  If `function1`, `function2`, and `function3` all do some common thing when `age > 60`, and `function1`, `function4`, and `function7` all do some common thing when `weight > 100`, then you might be able to split those functions apart, then put the common parts back together into new methods.

If you really have 9 different functions that have nothing in common, then there's no really good solution.  You could try setting up a map that maps all 9 combinations to functions:

```
Map<String, Runnable> functions = new HashMap<>();
functions.put("senior_heavy") = this::function1;
functions.put("senior_medium") = this::function2;
functions.put("senior_light") = this::function3;
functions.put("middleaged_heavy") = this::function4;
...
functions.put("child_light") = this::function9;
```

[You'd have to think of better names, since a 20-year-old isn't exactly middleaged.]

Then:

```
String ageString;
// set this to "senior", "middleaged", or "child"
String weightString;
// set this to "heavy", "medium", or "light"

functions.get(ageString + "_" + weightString).run();
```

`Runnable` is the interface for methods that take no parameters and don't return a result.  (For functions that take parameters and/or return results, there are other functional interface types that you'd use.  Or you could define your own as in smac89's answer, which would let you give a more descriptive name to the functional interface type.)  `this::function1` is a reference to `function1` belonging to the current object, `this`; if `function1` is `static`, however, you'd need to say `ThisClass::function1`.

This would eliminate the duplicated `if` pattern, but it's not a pretty solution.  If I were reviewing your code, I wouldn't complain much about your original code, since the alternatives aren't great either.  (A 2-D array of `Runnable` is another alternative.)

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly elegant.  In brief, make up a method that do that inner-condition-check, and allow the "action" for different case to be passed in

```
// Change to use other proper functional interface.  Using Runnable
// just to align with your sample code.
doOnWeight(int weight, 
           Runnable overWeightAction,
           Runnable normalWeightAction,                       
           Runnable underWeightAction) {
    if(weight>100){
        overWeightAction.apply();
    }else if(weight<40){
        underWeightAction.apply();
    }else{
        normalWeightAction.apply();
    }
}    
//.......

// your original code, I assume your functions are instance methods
if(age>60){
    doOnWeight(weight, this::function1, this::function3, this::function2)
}else if(age<20){
    doOnWeight(weight, this::function4, this::function6, this::function5)
}else{
    doOnWeight(weight, this::function7, this::function9, this::function8)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class User {
    int age;
    int weight;
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface WeightFunction {
    void perform(User user);
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface AgeFunction {

    WeightFunction getWeightFunction(User user);
}

public class Age60Function implements AgeFunction {
    @Override
    public WeightFunction getWeightFunction(User user) {
        String desc = "Age 60 ";
        if (user.weight > 100) {
            return weightUser -> System.out.println(desc + "Age > 100");
        } else if (user.weight < 40) {
            return weightUser -> System.out.println(desc + "Age < 40");
        }
        return weightUser -> System.out.println(desc + "100 > Age > 40");
    }

}
```

Then you can create outer if and create related AgeFunction and perform the function.

Also another suggestion **IF WEIGHT CATEGORY ARE CONSTANT FOR ALL AGE LIMITS,** as this example weight category 100+, 40- and 100>age>40 you can follow below implementation.

```
public interface AdvanceAgeFunction {
    WeightFunction get100PlusWeightFunction(User user);
    WeightFunction get40MinusWeightFunction(User user);
    WeightFunction getWeightFunction(User user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with was roughly this:

```
interface WeightFunc {
    void function();
}
```

```
public static final List<WeightFunc> weightFuncs = Arrays.asList(weightFunc1, weightFunc2,...);
```

Now inside your method

```
List<WeightFunc> choices = null;

if(age>60){
    choices = Arrays.asList(weightFuncs.get(0), weightFuncs.get(1), ...);
    // 1, 2, 3
}else if(age<20){
    choices = Arrays.asList(weightFuncs.get(3), weightFuncs.get(4), ...);
    // 4, 5, 6
}else{
    choices = Arrays.asList(weightFuncs.get(6), weightFuncs.get(7), ...);
    // 7, 8, 9
}

WeightFunc choice = null;

if(weight>100){
    choice = choices.get(0);
    //do something different
}else if(weight<40){
    choice = choices.get(1);
    //do something different
}else{
    choice = choices.get(2);
    //do something different
}
```

Now call it:

```
choice.function();
```

IMO, I prefer your initial method to this

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely get your question but from what I see it seems you wan't to lose your redundant code so here is what I suggest.

Create a temp variable suppose

```
int ageGroup;
```

and a function to compute the weight calculations where ageGroup is passed as a parameter

```
void CheckWeight(int ageGroup)
{
}
```

You can further reduce the redundant code by creating another function to manage your work done in function 1-9 in switch conditions.

Your final code blocks will look like this :

```
if(age>60){
    CheckWeight(1);
}else if(age<20){
    CheckWeight(2)
}else{
    CheckWeight(3)
}



void CheckWeight(int ageGroup)
{
    if(weight>100){
       Compute(ageGroup,1);
    }else if(weight<40){
       Compute(ageGroup,2);
    }else{
       Compute(ageGroup,3);
    }
}


void Compute(int ageGroup,int weightGroup)
{
    switch(ageGroup)
    {
        case 1: 
            switch(weightGroup)
            {
                case 1:
                    //func1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //func 2;
                    break;
                .
                .
            }    
            break;
       case 2:
       .
       .
       .
    }
}
```

This is the best I can come up with, there may be other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually age and weight are 2 independent dimensions, all we need to do is to collect different combinations and then determine which function to call. So let's preset combinations in a map and just get the handler and call, not a single if/else is needed.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public enum Section {

    AGE(20, 60),
    WEIGHT(40, 100);

    private int[] points;

    Section(int... points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public int indexOf(int value) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> points = Arrays.stream(this.points).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        points.add(value);
        Collections.sort(points);
        return IntStream.range(0, points.size())
                .filter(index -> Objects.equals(points.get(index), value))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Value not found"));
    }
}

class MyTest {
    private static Map<String, Function<Object, Object>> sectionHandlerMapper = new HashMap<>();

    private static Object function1(Object obj) {
        return "function1";
    }
    private static Object function2(Object obj) {
        return "function2";
    }
    private static Object function3(Object obj) {
        return "function3";
    }
    private static Object function4(Object obj) {
        return "function4";
    }
    private static Object function5(Object obj) {
        return "function5";
    }
    private static Object function6(Object obj) {
        return "function6";
    }
    private static Object function7(Object obj) {
        return "function7";
    }
    private static Object function8(Object obj) {
        return "function8";
    }
    private static Object function9(Object obj) {
        return "function9";
    }

    static {
        sectionHandlerMapper.put("2-2", MyTest::function1);
        sectionHandlerMapper.put("2-0", MyTest::function2);
        sectionHandlerMapper.put("2-1", MyTest::function3);
        sectionHandlerMapper.put("0-2", MyTest::function4);
        sectionHandlerMapper.put("0-0", MyTest::function5);
        sectionHandlerMapper.put("0-1", MyTest::function6);
        sectionHandlerMapper.put("1-2", MyTest::function7);
        sectionHandlerMapper.put("1-0", MyTest::function8);
        sectionHandlerMapper.put("1-1", MyTest::function9);
    }

    public static Object call(Object obj, int... indices) {
        String key = Arrays.stream(indices).boxed().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("-"));
        return sectionHandlerMapper.get(key).apply(obj);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int age = 19;
        int weight = 39;
        int ageIndex = Section.AGE.indexOf(age);
        int weightIndex = Section.WEIGHT.indexOf(weight);
        System.out.println(call("obj", ageIndex, weightIndex));
    }
}
```

As enum is used, it would be rather convenient to add more dimensions, just adding new enums, reconstructing 'sectionHandlerMapper' and modifying main() would work. It's easy to expand.